# Is there a way to have an Office365 subscribed calendar show as busy for others

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, office365, ics

Are there any tools that allow you to subscribe to an ICS feed in Office 365, but in reality, SYNCHRONIZE that feed to a secondary O365 calendar?

Use case: I've got my main calendar which I maintain. I'm also subscribed to my 'teaching calendar' which changes occasionally, outside my control. When someone wants to schedule a meeting with me from within my organization, I would like them to know that I am not available during my teaching periods. If events get added, removed, or updated in the subscribed calendar, those changes must be reflected in the 'real' calendar.

I would imagine that there might be a cloud service or sync widget out there somewhere that you could provide your O365 credentials and the ICS URL and it would 'do the magic' -- but can't seem to find anything like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I thought if you changed the default permission of your calendar for everyone to view your busy/free times then when someone tries to invite you to a meeting or appointment it will show in the scheduling assistant that you're free or busy.

Comment: I've tried this and it only lets you choose to publish 'real' calendars, not the subscribed ones.

Answer (score 0):

I almost have the same problem except I set my teaching calendar my self.
The only available way for me now is to copy the events from the other calendar to the default calendar. This is easy using Outlook 2016 and the copy process just pastes it to the same spot in your calendar.
In addition, You can select them all using Ctrl button then Copy and Paste them to your calendar.
I know this is not the smart solution but this is the only one I could come up with.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the synchronization problem, as when there are changes, a person needs to clear out all of the old data.