# Show as 'busy' to colleagues for appointments on a subscribed calendar, Microsoft Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I've read these two articles:

- [How do I automatically add events from a subscribed calendar to Outlook so I show as 'busy' during them?](https://superuser.com/questions/1718123/how-do-i-automatically-add-events-from-a-subscribed-calendar-to-outlook-so-i-sho)
- [Is there a way to have an Office365 subscribed calendar show as busy for others](https://superuser.com/questions/1046013/is-there-a-way-to-have-an-office365-subscribed-calendar-show-as-busy-for-others)

Neither yet has a solution.

I'm subscribing to a calendar (e.g. a personal calendar) on my work MS account. I want the two calendars to effectively 'join together' so that if I had a personal appointment I would appear as busy to colleagues. How can I do that?

Comment: As you found from these threads, now there isn't a way to do this built-in. What we can do is to vote the feedback.